# How does flask pass 2 arguments?

Tags: python, html, flask

```
@app.route('/report/<category>/')
def category_list(category):
    files = category_files(category)
    return render_template ('category.html',data={'data':files,'category':category})
```

I think I am doing this wrong, but how can I pass these 2 arguments: files and category to category.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 return render_template ('category.html', data=files, category=category)
```

you can pass as any variables you want

Comment: @ThomasXie I am glad that my answer helps you

Answer (score 4):

You passed in *one* variable, a dictionary, named `data`. It has `'data'` and `'category'` keys. You *could* just use `data['data']` and `data['category']` in your template.

But if you want them to be separate variables in your template, pass in those keys separately instead:

```
return render_template('category.html', data=files, category=category)
```

You can still use a dictionary, but then you should use the `**` keyword argument expansion syntax to have the keys applied as separate arguments:

```
variables = {'data': files, 'category': category}
return render_template('category.html', **variables)
```

Comment: i am trying  variables = {'data': files, 'category': category}
                   return render_template ('category.html', **variables)       what should i do if i want to show the category on html? i tried {{category}}  it doesn't work..

Comment: @ThomasXie: *doesn't work* doesn't tell me anything, really. `{{category}}` should just work fine. Simplify your template and try out some basic tests; if you still have a problem post a new question with a [mcve] so we can help you troubleshoot that.